# how to add an image along with text in a button in MFC?

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

Am having a hard time in adding image along with a text in a Button..I know that it can be done by enabling the owner draw function with bitmapbutton class..But I dont want to that..so is ther anyother way that i can add an image along with text without drawing the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using MFC Feature Pack, just cast your button into a `CMFCButton` class. Then you can call `CMFCButton::SetImage` to add the image.